# Page refresh calls the action listener function

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have a JSF application. In the home.xhtml, I have included 4 tabs. Each tab is a different xhtml form.  The first form has an action listener. The problem is on all 4 tabs if I refresh (F5) the page, the action listener gets called.
On click of the command button, I check the DB to check if there are existing employees with the same details. If yes, I show the confirm dialog to proceed with Generation. If the user clicks Yes here, the new ID is generated.  This generation function gets called again and again if I refresh the page. I made the call as ajax="false" as well but it does not help. If I make ajax="true", It does not let me change the tabs. The page sort of hangs. Please suggest me on how to stop this.

```
<h:form id="employeeIdGenerationForm" prependId="false">

        <p:confirmDialog id="confirmationID" widgetVar="confirmationVar" header="Confirmation" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode"
                message="#{employeeMaintenanceBean.employee.getWarningsList()}" 
                rendered="#{employeeMaintenanceBean.showExistingEmployeeWarning}" closable="false">
            
            <p:commandButton value="Yes" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" onclick="PF('confirmationVar').hide()"
                actionListener="#{employeeMaintenanceBean.generateEmployeeID}" ajax="false"
                update="@form:confirmation @form:msgPanel_EmployeeIDGeneration @form:firstName @form:surName" />
                
            <p:commandButton value="No" styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('confirmationVar').hide()"/>
        </p:confirmDialog>      

        <p:panel styleClass="messagePanel"
            style="color: #004986; font-size: 15px;"
            header="New Employee ID Generation">
            <br />
            <h:panelGrid columns="1" id="msgPanel_EmployeeIDGeneration"
                width="100%" align="center" style="text-align:center;">
                <p:messages />
            </h:panelGrid>

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" border="0">
                <h:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="First Name" />
                <p:inputText value="#{employeeMaintenanceBean.employee.firstName}"
                    id="firstName" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="First Name is mandatory" maxlength="50"
                    styleClass="value" />

                <h:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Last Name" />
                <p:inputText value="#{employeeMaintenanceBean.employee.lastName}"
                    id="surName" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Last Name is mandatory" maxlength="50"
                    styleClass="value" />

                <h:outputLabel styleClass="label" value="Comments" />
                <p:inputTextarea
                    value="#{employeeMaintenanceBean.employee.comments}" id="comments"
                    maxlength="256" styleClass="value" />

                <p:commandButton id="generateID" ajax="false"
                    actionListener="#{employeeMaintenanceBean.isExistingEmployee}"
                    title="Generate Employee ID" value="Generate Employee ID" update="@form:confirmationID @form:msgPanel_EmployeeIDGeneration">
                </p:commandButton>

            </h:panelGrid>

        </p:panel>

    </h:form>
```

The main home.xhtml is:

```
      <h:head/>
<h:body>
    
    <ui:composition template="/template/common/commonLayout.xhtml">
    
        <ui:define name="content">
        
            <p:idleMonitor timeout="300000">
                <p:ajax event="idle" listener="#{baseBean.sessionTimeOut}"/>
            </p:idleMonitor>
        
            <p:tabView id="tabView" activeIndex="#{tabViewBean.mainTabActiveIndex}" dynamic="true" cache="false">
            
                <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{tabViewBean.onMainTabChange}" update="tabView" />                 

                <p:tab id="employeeIdGeneration" title="New Employee ID Generation"  rendered="#{tabViewBean.currentUser.hasAccessToPage('employeeIdGeneration')}">
                    <ui:include src="employeeIdGeneration.xhtml"/>
                </p:tab>

                <p:tab id="employeeMaintenance" title="Update New Employee Details" rendered="#{tabViewBean.currentUser.hasAccessToPage('employeeMaintenance')}">
                    <ui:include src="employeeIdMaintenance.xhtml"/>
                </p:tab>
                
                <p:tab id="employeeHistoryView" title="New Employee Update History" rendered="#{tabViewBean.currentUser.hasAccessToPage('employeeHistoryView')}">
                    <ui:include src="employeeHistoryView.xhtml"/>
                </p:tab>
                
                <p:tab id="userAccessMaintenance" title="User Access Maintenance" rendered="#{tabViewBean.currentUser.hasAccessToPage('userAccessMaintenance')}">
                    <ui:include src="userMaintenance.xhtml"/>
                </p:tab>
                
            </p:tabView>
            
        </ui:define>
        
    </ui:composition>
    
</h:body>
```

Comment: Can you post the mail xhtml that includes the others?

Comment: I added the main page/home.xtml. Please check.

Comment: Which is the actionListener execute after the f5? If you debug this behavior with a browser developer tool you should see for each call which is the source that launches it. After that I would remove `update="tabView"` that seems redundant, else I would remove that template and give it a try. As a last try, I would add a default command to the form, that does nothing